# Android twitter authorization failed

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, android-4.4-kitkat

I am having a twitter share option in my android application.I am using `twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar`. It is working in android version-4.3 (api level-18), but it is showing error in android version-4.4.2 (api level-19). I am getting an error like this:

```
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(197)] openSSL SYSCALL error,earliest error code in error queue: 0, errno: 0
```